# HTML Bootstrap form styling

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

how can i make this list show me the buttons above the textboxes? as in

[Ideal formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osJ1z.png)

code is:

```
 <form id="Data" runat="server" class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-dark">
     <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="Countries" class="control-label">Email address</label>
            <asp:DropDownList name="Countries" ID="Countries" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Countries_Selected">
            <asp:ListItem Text="<Seleccione país>" Value="0" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="DateIn" class="control-label">Email address</label>
            <asp:Textbox runat="server" TextMode="Date" name="DateIn" ID="DateIn" Text="Seleccione Fecha Devolucion">
            </asp:Textbox>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="DateOut" class="control-label">Email address</label>
            <asp:Textbox runat="server" TextMode="Date" name="DateOut" ID="DateOut" Text="Seleccione Fecha Retiro">
            </asp:Textbox>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group col">
        <label for="smth" class="control-label">Email address</label>
            <asp:DropDownList name="smth" ID="smth" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Countries_Selected">
                <asp:ListItem Text="<Seleccione país>" Value="0" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
     </div>

    </form>
```

Currently my page is showing like:

[Current style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK9uO.png)

Comment: Bootstrap 4 doesn't have `col-xs` it is just `col`.

Comment: So i'll assume col-md is not doing anything either?

Comment: `col-md` is valid, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `rows`, one with two `col-6` and one with two `col-3`. I have used just a single inline css style. You do not need to do so if the form is inside an another element with the same size. Otherwise, change it to whatever number that passes your design.

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form class="bg-success p-4 text-white mx-auto" style="width:500px">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
          <label for="DateIn">Fecha y Horario regreso</label>
          <input class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
          <label for="Countries"> Categorias:</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option value="">one</option>
            <option value="">two</option>
            <option value="">three</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-3">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option value="">one</option>
            <option value="">two</option>
            <option value="">three</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option value="">one</option>
            <option value="">two</option>
            <option value="">three</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

## Update

Follow these steps

1. make form a row
2. `col-6` for the two first column
3. `col` break to force the last two column to new line
4. `col-3` for the last tow `columns`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="row bg-success p-4 text-white mx-auto" style="width: 500px;">
  <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
    <label for="DateIn">Fecha y Horario regreso</label>
    <input class="form-control radius-0">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column">
    <label for="Countries"> Categorias:</label>
    <select class="form-control radius-0">
      <option value="">one</option>
      <option value="">two</option>
      <option value="">three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- Force next columns to break to new line at md breakpoint and up -->
  <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block my-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <select class="form-control radius-0">
      <option value="">one</option>
      <option value="">two</option>
      <option value="">three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <select class="form-control radius-0">
      <option value="">one</option>
      <option value="">two</option>
      <option value="">three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvoyop)

As you see the form elements are curvier than the one in the img. If you are using `SCSS` change the radius. Otherwise, change it with css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` to get the layout. You will need to make more tweaks to get the inputs to match the styling.

I made two helper classes: `columns` and `col`.

`columns` is a container div with `display: flex`. `col` is each column in the div with `flex: 1` which means they will be evenly spaced within a container.

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
  background: #278339;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
}

input,
select {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form id="Data" runat="server" class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-dark">

  <div class="columns">

    <div class="col">

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="DateIn" class="control-label">Fecha y Horario regreso</label>
        <input runat="server" TextMode="Date" name="DateIn" ID="DateIn" Text="Seleccione Fecha Devolucion">
        </input>
      </div>

      <div class="columns">

        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <select name="Countries" ID="Countries" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Countries_Selected">
              <option Text="<Seleccione país>" Value="0" />
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">

          <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <select name="Countries" ID="Countries" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Countries_Selected">
              <option Text="<Seleccione país>" Value="0" />
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="Countries" class="control-label">Categorias:</label>
        <select name="Countries" ID="Countries" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Countries_Selected">
          <option Text="<Seleccione país>" Value="0" />
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Sorry im a total noob regarding CSS, it seems the class col is already created in bootstrap 4, would that be a problem? if i create it again?

Comment: @GonzaloIgnacioVeraPortilla Yeah then you should change the name to `my-col` or whatever is unique, the class name can be anything.

Comment: @mahan Where's your answer at?

Comment: @mahan I'd say the same, your comment doesn't help at all with the issue, if you wanna point a mistake in somebody's answer please do with the details and alternate solution